# What's the better way to add an inline script?

Tags: php, wordpress

What's the better way to add an inline script in wordpress, is it by the function wp_add_inline_script, or using the hook wp_footer ?
and why ?

Comment: If you get no answers here, you may get more answers at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok, i'll try it, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion: `wp_add_inline_script` because you need to enqueue main script file before this inline script is called.

With `wp_footer` you only add script content but is not warantee main script is enqueue.

This example is from wp_add_inline_script codex page (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) and helps to understand this concept:

```
function mytheme_enqueue_typekit() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-typekit', 'https://use.typekit.net/.js', array(), '1.0' );
   wp_add_inline_script( 'mytheme-typekit', 'try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_typekit' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation would be the first option if you have dependencies for the script:

```
wp_add_inline_script();
```

This is also a nice way to allow you to modify your inline scripts via a child theme or plugin should you wish.

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/